# UITableView doesn't reload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with updating the `UITableView`. I call the `reloadData` method on it, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't get called. Code:

```
//.h
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController<ELCTextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
  //some variables
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *theTableView;
//other properties

//.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  //some code
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
  self.theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480 - 64);
  [self.theTableView reloadData];
}
```

I connected the `theTableView` with `UITableView` in the xib and I also set it's `delegate` and `dataSource` to `File's Owner`.

I use `ELCTextFieldCell` which provides me with a `UITableViewCell` with a `UILabel` and a `UITextField`. I insert some values in the cells and when the keyboard hides that tableView should reload it's data to show the correct result in one of the cells. I did some debugging and calculations work as it should, but that cell doesn't refresh(as I mentioned the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method doesn't get called after `[self.theTableView reloadData]`.

Thank you.

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

Found an "ugly" solution for that. Instead of calling

```
[self.theTableView reloadData];
```

I called

```
[self.theTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

It's ugly and hard-coded which may lead to problems later if I will add more cells or remove some, but it works.

Still looking for a solution that would use `reloadData` method

Comment: may be the tableview instance is null. That'y it is not working. Keep NSLog(@"theTableView %@",theTableView); and check.

Comment: Where you are allocating memory to table view?

Comment: @Dee it's not. The cell refreshes if I scroll it off the screen and show again. Debugger at the first line of keyboradWillHide shows the following: `(UITableView *) $7 = 0x079f3e00 <UITableView: 0x79f3e00; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6b0aef0>; contentOffset: {-0, -0}>`. So I guess that it's not the case

Comment: @rishi nowhere in the code. Only connecting it in the xib

Comment: @Novarg - you need to initialise your tableview, as won't have any memory that's why it is not working.

Comment: found an "ugly" solution for that. Instead of calling `[self.theTableView reloadData]` I called `[self.theTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]`. It's ugly and hard-coded which may lead to problems later if I will add more cells or remove some, but it's working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reloadData` redisplays **only** visible rows (for efficiency). The fact that you set your tableview's frame just before `reloadData` makes me think that the tableview for some reason doesn't see that the particular cell is visible at that time, so it doesn't ask for a new one (and this explains why after scrolling down/up it refreshes correctly). Try to poll your tableview to see what reports as visible cells prior calling `reloadData` (`[theTableView visibleCells];`). I hope that this will help you track the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what was happening. The tableView was becoming bigger to take the whole screen while the keyboard was still visible. Therefore the cell that should have been updated was covered by the keyboard. Just changed the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Table is reloaded only if u have some changes in table.....

Comment: the dictionary that is used as a data source is being modified

Comment: Are You getting data in table when u run first time your project

Comment: mean in starting there is no data in your dictionary?

Comment: exactly. I just initialize the dictionary in viewDidLoad and set a couple of pre-defined values in

Comment: when I type in some values into the text fields. And once after all the calculations are done to set the result there

Answer (score 0):

check if `tableView` is not nil... if so allocate memory

what is returning in the

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

both returning non zero value than it should be called

Comment: They return 1 and 8 respectively as it should

Comment: both above methods getting called ? then check if you have connected data source and delegate outlet are connected to class and your your class declares <UItableViewDelegate>

Comment: also check above both method are not interchanged by mistake... just guessing ...

Comment: yes, they are getting called. Yes, I connected both. And what do you mean by intercharging?